# How To create a Cloud Run container by using Python Library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-apis-explorer

How to create a container of cloud run by python library like from google.cloud import run_v2,

I am not getting any example for creating container with by python code

Comment: Refer to the Python SDK and write code. Once you have written code and have a problem, post a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to create a service account and credentials here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=

Next, you need to either download the key or use any other authentication method, in my example, the key.

```
# init credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("prject-key.json")

# create client
import google.cloud.run_v2 as run_v2
run_client = run_v2.ServicesClient(credentials=credentials)

# build request
from google.cloud.run_v2 import ListServicesRequest
request = ListServicesRequest(
    parent="projects/{projectnumber}/locations/{location}"
)

# response
response = run_client.list_services(request=request)
```

Here you can find samples: https://github.com/googleapis/python-run/tree/main/samples/generated_samples

Also keep in mind that permissions work depending on the authentication method. Somewhere the IP whitelist is indicated somewhere not